# login_required decorator doesnt work, flask-Login permits anonymous users

Tags: python, flask

I decorated a method with `login_required`, but I am surprised that its not **executing** at all, allowing in anonymous users. Printing the `current_user` within the method returns this:

```
<flask_login.AnonymousUserMixin object at 0xb67dbd4c>
```

Is it not supposed to reject users which return false in `user.is_autheticated()`? What did I do wrong?

---

I have setup FL this way:

```
lm = LoginManager(app)
lm.login_view = 'root'
```

in views.py:

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

the actual view:

```
@login_required
@app.route("/messages")
def messages():
    print "current user", current_user
    return "hello world"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Serendipity gave me [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/viewdecorators/):

> When applying further decorators, always remember that the route() decorator is the outermost:

I wrote it the wrong way (route not the outermost).

---

[PDB](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-debugging-testing-and-profiling) can execute your suspect method in debug mode, to inspect the local state.

Flask-Login is present in GitHub anyway and the source of `login_required` is simple enough to understand.

Comment: Hi, I just got here and I had the same exact experience

Comment: This is the correct answer, it saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 6):

Everything looks OK, which probably means the problem is somewhere else.

What is the configuration you are using? If `LOGIN_DISABLED` or `TESTING` is set to true, authentication is disabled.

If your configuration is fine, set a breakpoint inside `login_required` decorator and check why it lets anonymous user in.

Comment: I feel so dumb to have been caught by this.