# Flask: why app.route() decorator, should always be the outermost?

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

Say, I have a hand-crafted `@login-required` decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def login_required(decorated_function):
    """Decorator to check if user is logged in."""

        @wraps(decorated_function)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if False: # just to check it's working
            return decorated_function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login, to access this page')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrapper
```

and a function, decorated with `@app.route()` and `@login_required` (*endpoint for `login` omitted for brevity*):

```
@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return "Hello!"
```

Now, if I try to access `/`, as expected, it won't let me and will redirect to the login page.

Though, if I swipe the the order of the decorators i.e.:

```
@login_required
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello!"
```

then I am able to access `/`, even though I shouldn't be.

I am aware that [Flask documentation on the subject](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/viewdecorators/#login-required-decorator) states:

> When applying further decorators, always remember that the route() decorator is the outermost.

I have also seen [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575234/login-required-trouble-in-flask-app) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288773/login-required-decorator-doesnt-work-flask-login-permits-anonymous-users) on the same issue.

---

What I'm curious about is not what is the proper way to do it (*`@app.route()` decorator must be outermost - got it*), but rather why it is working this way (i.e. what is the mechanics behind it).

I took a look at `@app.route()` [source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py):

```
   def route(self, rule, **options):
    def decorator(f):
        endpoint = options.pop('endpoint', None)
        self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
        return f
    return decorator
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/8554766), helped me to understand mechanism of decorators, more or less. Though, I have never seen function just returned (without calling it) before, so I did a little experiment myself (which turned out to be workable, of course):

```
def my_decorator():
    def decorator (function):
        return function
    return decorator

@my_decorator()
def test():
    print('Hi')

test()
```

So, I would like to understand:

- Why order of decorators matter in the exact case above and for `@app.route()` and other decorators in general (which is the same answer, I guess)? What confuses me, is that `@app.route()` just adds url rule to the app (i.e. `self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)` and returns the function, that's it, so why would order matter?
- Does `@app.route()` overrides all the decorators above it (how if so)?

I am also [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28204335/8554766), that decorators application order is from bottom to top, though it doesn't make things any clearer, for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have almost explained it yourself! :-)  `app.route` does

```
self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
```

But the key is that `f` here is whatever function was decorated.  If you apply `app.route` first, it adds a URL rule for the original function (without the login decorator).  The login decorator wraps the function, but `app.route` has already stored the original unwrapped version, so the wrapping has no effect.

It may help to envision "unrolling" the decorators.  Imagine you did it like this:

```
# plain function
def index():
    return "Hello!"

login_wrapped = login_required(index)         # login decorator
both_wrapped = app.route('/')(login_wrapped)  # route decorator
```

This is the "right" way where the login wrap happens first and then the route.  In this version, the function that `app.route` sees is already wrapped with the login wrapper.  The wrong way is:

```
# plain function
def index():
    return "Hello!"

route_wrapped = app.route('/')(index)        # route decorator
both_wrapped = login_wrapped(route_wrapped)  # login decorator
```

Here you can see that what `app.route` sees is only the plain unwrapped version.  The fact that the function is *later* wrapped with the login decorator has no effect, because by that time the route decorator has already finished.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive explanation. The funny thing is: right after posting the question — I went though [this article](https://ains.co/blog/things-which-arent-magic-flask-part-1.html), which basically explains how to write your own `@app.route()` (_and thus, how `@app.route()` works in Flask_), and understood it myself =).